# span text on top of image

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, html

Searched everything but can't find a answer to my question.

I want the price to be on top of the image having the following code.

who can help me with this please?

HTML

```
<li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail cart_item" ><span class="item_price price">€ 18.50</span>
                            <img alt="" src="http://test.jpg">
                            <div class="caption" >
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail>img {
display: block;  
max-width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.price {
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.4em;
background: #96c42e;
padding: 8px 8px 10px 8px;
    position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-top: -8px;
margin-right: -10px;
-moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the adding the following:

```
.thumbnail{
    position:relative;
}

.price {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background: #96c42e;
    padding: 8px 8px 10px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top:0px;
    left:auto;
    right:0px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
    z-index:100;
}
```

Give the container `position:relative` then place the price tag using `position:absolute`.